# Decimal overflow VB 2012

Tags: vb.net

Visual Studios help guide says the maximum possible value for it to store in a decimal is 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 Whenever I put a large number the program does nothing at all so I wanted to display an error message for the user asking them to enter a smaller value or somehow detect an overflow. I tried using

```
If lengtha = 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 Then
                MsgBox("Can not compute, try a smaller value.")
            End If
```

but it did not work out. Here is the code so far.

```
Class MainWindow 

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click
    Dim length As String = LengthTextBox.Text
    If IsNumeric(length) Then


    Else
        MsgBox("The value entered in legnth is not numeric, please enter a numeric value.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")

    End If

    Dim width As String = WidthTextBox.Text
    If IsNumeric(width) Then


    Else
        MsgBox("The value entered in width is not numeric, please enter a numeric value.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")

    End If

    Try
        Dim lengtha As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(length)
        If lengtha < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Length can not be negative.")
            Return
        End If

        Dim widtha As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(width)
        If widtha < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Width can not be negative.")
            Return
        End If
        Dim calculations1 As Decimal = lengtha * widtha
        AnswerLabel.Content = "Area: " + calculations1.ToString
        Dim calculations2 As Decimal = lengtha * 2 + widtha * 2
        answerLabel2.Content = "Perimeter: " + calculations2.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Do not swallow exceptions like that. It is really a bad practice unless there are really good reason to suppress them.

Answer (score 2):

Please, stop using `IsNumeric` to check if a string could be considered a number.
`IsNumeric` is a relic of VB6 and [its disandvantage are numerous](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/131440-isnumeric-vs-tryparse/) and well known.

You should use [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Decimal.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check and convert a potentially decimal value hidden in a string to its decimal type and you don't use an empty try/catch to hide exceptions.
In that way, if you have an error in your code you will have difficult times to diagnoses it.

So let me try a different approach

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click

    Dim lengtha As Decimal 
    Dim length As String = LengthTextBox.Text
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(length, legtha) Then
        MsgBox("The value entered in length is not numeric, please enter a numeric value.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        Return
    End If
    If lengtha < 0 Then
         MsgBox("Length can not be negative.")
         Return
    End If

    Dim widtha As Decimal 
    Dim width As String = WidthTextBox.Text
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(width, widtha) Then
        MsgBox("The value entered in width is not numeric, please enter a numeric value.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        Return
    End If
    If widtha < 0 Then
         MsgBox("Width can not be negative.")
         Return
    End If

    Try
        Dim calculations1 As Decimal = lengtha * widtha
        AnswerLabel.Content = "Area: " + calculations1.ToString
        Dim calculations2 As Decimal = lengtha * 2 + widtha * 2
        answerLabel2.Content = "Perimeter: " + calculations2.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

There are also two possible problems to be aware of.

First, if your user types the numbers with the thousand separators as you have shown, then you need to use a different version of TryParse, the one that allows to pass a NumberStyle enum and a NumericFormatInfo

```
If Not Decimal.TryParse(length, _
        NumerStyles.AllowThousands Or NumberStyles.AllowDecimal,  _
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, legtha) Then
```

Second, the multiplactions executed to get the values of `calculations1` and `calculations2` could result in a value that is too big to be represented by a decimal variable and you could get an Overflow exception. This problem is difficult to solve without konowing the context that required the input of Width and Length values. Perhaps a check on the maximum length in characters of the string could avoid it

Answer (score 0):

If lengtha = 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 Then
                MsgBox("Can not compute, try a smaller value.")
            End If

Will only check for exact matches. I guess you also want larger numbers.
Maybe you can check if the number of characters is less than 30 and the first two are less than 79.

Also make sure culture info is correct as some countries use . and , the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not very elegant code but maybe you can understand it better. Try to parse the strings with Decimal.Tryparse and act accordingly. See the code comments for further explanations.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Save input strings in easier variables
    Dim inputLength As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim inputWidth As String = TextBox2.Text

    Dim length, width As Decimal 'These will hold our results

    'Tryparse tries to convert the string to decimal. Returns true if successful
    'and false if not successful. If true then the result-field will also hold the
    'converted value
    Dim IsLengthOk As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(inputLength, length)
    Dim IsWidthOk As Boolean = Decimal.TryParse(inputWidth, width)

    'Create an error message if either of the values is invalid and exit the sub if so
    Dim ErrorString As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    If Not IsLengthOk Then ErrorString.AppendLine("The value you entered for length is not a valid number.")
    If Not IsWidthOk Then ErrorString.AppendLine("The value you entered for width is not a valid number.")
    If Not IsLengthOk OrElse Not IsWidthOk Then
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorString.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Now check the values if they are larger than zero (you could also just use
    'Math.Abs(length) to make the numbers positive
    IsLengthOk = (length > 0) 'assign the result of the comparison to the boolean variables
    IsWidthOk = (width > 0)

    'Again, create error messages if there are errors
    ErrorString.Clear()
    If Not IsLengthOk Then ErrorString.AppendLine("Length must be larger than zero!")
    If Not IsWidthOk Then ErrorString.AppendLine("Width must be larger than zero!")
    If Not IsLengthOk OrElse Not IsWidthOk Then
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorString.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Calculate now your results and output them
    Dim calculations1 As Decimal = length * width
    AnswerLabel.Content = "Area: " + calculations1.ToString
    Dim calculations2 As Decimal = length * 2 + width * 2
    answerLabel2.Content = "Perimeter: " + calculations2.ToString
End Sub
```